# Using Android Studio with GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio

I notice that Android Studio does have basic support for accessing a GitHub project but all the features I was use to with EGit in Eclipse don't seem to be available, like merging and creating branches, viewing code differences, etc.

Should I be using GitHub's desktop app to manage code versioning and just synchronize my code in Android Studio whenever I do a commit? Or is there an alternative way? I understand that Android Studio is built on IntelliJ? Does that mean that it supports some kind of equivalent plugin like EGit?

UPDATE: After playing around some more with Android Studio, I discovered that a lot more of the Git functionality is available but it's scattered around in various menus that are not exactly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), in combination with the commandline.

> *Git Extensions is the only graphical user interface for Git that allows you control Git without using the commandline. It comes with a manual and video tutorials to get you started quickly.*

[image]

About "synchronizing code in Android Studio", this is done automatically. As soon as you checkout some other branch, navigating back to AS will update the filetree.